# Переменная из массива в запросе UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго всем времени суток господа. Второй раз за сегодня

```
$cena = $massiv["cena"];
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE `table` SET `cena`='$cena' WHERE `id`='$id'");
```

Есть запрос к таблице, потом идет обновление записи таблице. Между запросом и обновлением я приравниваю цену к переменной, т.к. запрос типа...

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE `table` SET `cena`='$massiv["cena"]' WHERE `id`='$id'");
```

... выдает ошибку. Собственно можно конечно дописать...

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE `table` SET `cena`='$massiv["cena"]' WHERE `id`='$id'") or die("no connect to bd");
```

... но это только скрывает ошибку в запросе. Экранировать спец знаки пробовал. Толи неправильно, то ли не срабатывает это.

Вопрос: можно ли в запросе (в моем случае) как то вписать переменную из массива?

p.s. если так нельзя - прошу прямо сказать об этом, т.к. тоже какой ни какой ответ

Comment: Несколько советов:

 1. Пора использовать программу с подсветкой синтаксиса
 2. Пора учить php
 3. Пора переходить на PDO

И по ошибкам в коде:


    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE `table` SET `cena`='$massiv["cena"]' WHERE `id`='$id'"); //это код с синтаксической ошибкой
    
    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE `table` SET `cena`='".$massiv['cena']."' WHERE `id`='".$id."';"); // а этот уже нет

Comment: ок. что ж в комментарии, а не в ответе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `table` SET `cena`='{$massiv['cena']}' WHERE `id`='{$id}'");
```

Обрати внимание на фигурные скобки вокруг твоих переменных